# How to go back to lines edited before the last one in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm aware of the `` `. `` command that goes to last edited line. Is there a way to go further in the editing history? I often accidentally insert something while browsing the file, undo, but then `` `. `` will not bring me where I want anymore.

Comment: `''` is more convenient than `'.`

Comment: @AA not when you have dead keys on your keyboard.

Comment: @AA be aware that `''` brings you back  to the line before your last jump whereas `'.` to the line of your last edit

Comment: with `'`, one jumps to the first non-whitespace character of a marked line (last edit, before jump, mark etc.) whereas `\`` brings you to the exact cursor position, so considering line **AND** column.

Answer (score 391):

Try <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd>.  They jump backward and forward in the changelist.

See `:help changelist` for more details.

Comment: Till now, I used to use this hack of undo followed by redo to go to last changed position. i.e. "u" and then "ctrl+r".

Comment: @Bob - are you still alive? please can you make judgement call on correct answer. This answer has enough votes to warrant serious contention ;)

Comment: Oh, where is @Bod now, you should mark this is the right answer, there are many OCD person here.

Comment: [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2002/20754) works for me

Comment: FTR: these commands are `g` `;` and `g` `,` i.e. semicolon and comma. (In my browser the `kbd`-font makes it look like `g` `:` and `g` `.`, which does not work.)

Answer (score 74):

I use <kbd>CTRL-O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL-I</kbd> to jump back and forth between recent points in files. It also goes through certain motion commands, but I find it usually takes me back to where I was editing.

Comment: These commands move through the 'jumplist' (`:help jumplist`), whereas `g;` and `g,` scroll through the 'changelist'.

Comment: I found this quite useful, even if it didn't answer the question directly

Comment: Note, Tab is a more convenient way of typing Ctrl+I