# Navigate though previous edit points in vim?

Tags: vim, text, editor

Is it possible in vim to navigate recursively to previous edit points (i.e. points where the text has been changed)? Such a feature would be incredibly useful for $\TeX$ document editing, where you often need to move large chunks of text fairly large distances, and navigation can get quite confusing.

Plugins with this functionality are welcome, if it can't be done with basic vim.

Comment: Something like Ctrl-O and Ctrl-I?

Comment: @Idigas I think so. Stick that in an answer, and I'll accept it. If you can explain the jumpslist more coherently than the manual, that'd be greatly appreciated (especially the conditions under which jumps are created).

Comment: Alas no, sorry. Wish I could, but I don't use them that often - merely know of them. Generally, I believe they're the last places where your cursor was before editing, or doing some window opeartions.

Comment: `C-o` and `C-i` go through the jumplist, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722681/vim-go-to-last-edited-line/1722706#1722706) answer for how to jump through the changelist.  Similar but useful none the less.

Comment: hey @RandyMorris, that's actually a more appropriate answer. Please post it as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `g;` to move to where the last change occurred.

`g,` moves back to more recent changes.

`:changes` shows you where `g;` and `g,` will take you.

`gi` is the same as `g;` except it also starts insert mode.

Comment: I've been using this for a while now. Found out about it, but I'd forgotten about the question by then. Thanks for posting an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Something like `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-I`? These cycle through the 'jumplist' (`O` goes backwards, `I` forwards), which is the list of previous edits and jumps.

You can print the current jumpslist with `:ju[mps]`

For more detail on this funcitonality, check `:h jumpslist`