# Move over last editing positionS

Tags: vim

I want to see complete list of editing positions, not just a last one like `'.`
Jumps (`<c-o>` & `<c-i>`) are not it, since you can edit few times without any jump.

Is something like that possible or plugin should be implemented ?

**EDIT**

Enter in the blank line `some text<esc>` then do `0i1<esc>` after that `$a2<esc>` then `o<esc>`. I want to have a key to return first to `2` then `1`. `g;`/`g,` do not do that, they see those 2 edits as single one.

**SOLUTION**

It appears that this works

```
set fo=
au InsertEnter * set tw=1 
au InsertLeave * set tw=78
```

After that you can use `g;` / `g,`

Comment: Would `:changes` and `g;`/`g,` be what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically, you want the functionality of the built-in `g;` / `g,` commands **without** the special treatment described at their `:help`:

> When two undo-able changes are in the same line and at a column position less
>   than 'textwidth' apart only the last one is remembered.  This avoids that a
>   sequence of small changes in a line, for example "xxxxx", adds many positions
>   to the change list.  When 'textwidth' is zero 'wrapmargin' is used.  When that
>   also isn't set a fixed number of 79 is used.  Detail: For the computations
>   bytes are used, not characters, to avoid a speed penalty (this only matters
>   for multi-byte encodings).

Unfortunately, you only have two options:

1. Write your own plugin that records the insert positions (e.g. via an `:autocmd InsertLeave`, but capturing changes from other modes will be harder), and provides mappings to jump to them.
2. Modify Vim's source code to adapt the mentioned special treatment to what you have in mind.

Comment: Ah, I saw your post after I edited mine to include g; and g, . It seems that's what the OP was looking for indeed. Your added comments get my vote: +1 for you

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have behavior described in the help with tw=1 unless I am inside the comment. Formatoptions are `tcroql`

Comment: I guess `l` parameter is responsible: _Long lines are not broken in insert mode: When a line was longer than 'textwidth' when the insert command started, Vim does not automatically format it._

Comment: I added answer to the question. You can actually disable this behavior and still benefit from tw=1 if you remove `t` and `q` from `&fo`

Comment: I personally wouldn't mess with `'fo'` just for this, but if it makes you happy, why not?!

Comment: `fo` can be set and restored after insert just as `tw`

Answer (score 1):

- Edit: try http://lifehacker.com/202093/go-back-in-text-file-time-with-vim-70
    it could be what you were looking for
- You may want to try:

  `:ju` (show all the "jumps", ie places where you went in the file. Not always places where you edited, though)

  If you want to jump directly to the "position n-3" :  `3 <c-o>` will do that
- Another way: `g ;` to go back and `g ,` to go forward
- Another way: You can "mark" positions, and refer to them later

  `ma` mark the current position and labels it "a"
  `mb` mark another position, and labels it "b"

  then

  `'a` goes back to position a,  `'b` goes to position b.

  it also works in commands :

  `:.,'as/^/# /` : add "# " in front of the lines from the current one (.) to the one where mark a is ('a)
  (etc)
- Another way: to quickly jump to the SAME word you are currently over (usefull to jump from function definition to function usage(s): `*` (until you reach the one you want)

Comment: I don't want to mark. I often feel the need to jump to previous edit positions that edited just recently (like last minute). I don't want to prepare for this, it should always be there.

Comment: I added (as the First bullet) a new way available in recent vims : http://lifehacker.com/202093/go-back-in-text-file-time-with-vim-70  "a new feature has been included which allows a user to jump back or forward to any point of editing" ... But it does "go back", ie unravel changes... not just jumps to the point you were at

Comment: I added that you can jump to the n'th previous position by : `n<C-o>`

Comment: Finally : Another way [I added that as a new 3rd bullet]: `g ;` to go back and `g ,` to go forward  (of course you can add numbers before! like `3 g ;`) (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722681/vim-go-to-last-edited-line )

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `g-`.  See also `:help :undolist`.  For full details, read

```
:help undo-tree
:help usr_32.txt
```

Edit: As the comment pointed out, this is not what the question asked for.  I was really thinking of `g;` and `g,`, as mentioned by @Olivier Dulac.

Comment: That is simply undo. TBH, undo is closest to what I want, i just don't want it to actually do undo, just move the cursor. This might be harder then I imagined on more thought ...