# How to go to the last edit location across all buffers in vim?

Tags: vim

It is easy to go to the last edit location in the current buffer.
See [How to go back to lines edited before the last one in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722681/vim-go-to-last-edited-line)
The changelist is buffer local, each buffer has it's own changelist.
However it is very common that I navigate away from that recently edited buffer to an other buffer, and it would be nice to somehow get back to the last edit location in the original buffer. Is there a way to go back to the place where the last insert or modify has happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the following in your vimrc

```
autocmd InsertLeave * execute 'normal! mI'
```

and press <kbd>`</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to jump back to the position where you left your Insert mode. Since `I` is an uppercase, it works across buffers.

---

Addendum (after the comment)

After reading @Garbor Marton's comment,

I wrote a function myself

```
let g:detect_mod_reg_state = -1
function! DetectRegChangeAndUpdateMark()
    let current_small_register = getreg('"-')
    let current_mod_register = getreg('""')
    if g:detect_mod_reg_state != current_small_register || 
                \ g:detect_mod_reg_state != current_mod_register
        normal! mM
        let g:detect_mod_reg_state = current_small_register
    endif
endfunction

" Mark I at the position where the last Insert mode occured across the buffer
autocmd InsertLeave * execute 'normal! mI'

" Mark M at the position when any modification happened in the Normal or Insert mode
autocmd CursorMoved * call DetectRegChangeAndUpdateMark()
autocmd InsertLeave * execute 'normal! mM'
```

I liked using the original `I` register specifically for the insert mode change, so here I use a `M` register for any modification including `r,x,d,y` AND last insert mode.

Comment: This is quite good, but would it be possible to `execute 'normal! mI'` when r,x,d and other modify commands have been used in normal mode?

Comment: I added the addendum @GaborMarton

Comment: Maybe publish in GitLab as a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You could do `:windo normal`<kbd>`</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

That said, I usually just use <kbd>C-o</kbd> (repeatedly).

If I "feel" that I will likely want to return to some point, I'll just hit `mA` (which records a cross-file/buffer mark) so I can just do <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> from anywhere (even after restarting the editor).

---

Slightly off-topic, I love `:Obsession` (by Tim Pope) for really long-lived sessions that do a lot of cross-reference navigation.

Comment: with :windo normal I would loose the actual positions in all windows, though I just want to go back in the currently active window. Also `. is buffer local.

Comment: Ctrl-o is really useful, but it is going back in the jumplist. So e.g. if I had done a search previously than it will go over all the search jumps as well. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Ok. I actually read that as "I want all my windows to revert to _their_ last edit positions". Since it turns out you just wanted last edit position, I think there's nothing better than `C-o`-ing there (or marking the location before you navigate elsewhere ofcourse).

Comment: Have a look at **[`g;` and `g,`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#g;) motion commands** though. Did you know you can use `[count]` with all of those (also `C-o` and `C-I`)?

Comment: Probably the best would be if vim would automatically add a global mark when a modification happened. I.e when insert mode is left or when r,x,d and other modify commands have been used in normal mode. I guess this could be done right now only with a plugin.

Comment: Yes. Looks like judicious use of `:buf <pattern>` (or `C-^`) and then `'"`, `'.`,  (or even `'^`?) would go a long way to achieving your goal

Answer (score 0):

Try doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>).

Comment: ctrl-6 would change to the alternate file, which is not necessarily the file I last modified. E.g. if I modify fileA, then open fileB, then open fileC: the alternate file will be fileB, and not fileA though I did not modify fileB.